# Heartbeat token failed

Tags: webserver, debug, cluster, token

**I have a new one today : this !**

```
root@lab-web2:/etc/heartbeat# systemctl status heartbeat
● heartbeat.service - Heartbeat High Availability Cluster Communication and Membership
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/heartbeat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-07-19 10:11:23 CEST; 5s ago
Docs: man:heartbeat(8)
http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Documentation
Main PID: 1806 (heartbeat)
Tasks: 6 (limit: 1115)
Memory: 10.7M
CPU: 214ms
CGroup: /system.slice/heartbeat.service
├─1806 heartbeat: master control process
├─1810 heartbeat: FIFO reader
├─1811 heartbeat: write: bcast ens192
├─1812 heartbeat: read: bcast ens192
├─1813 heartbeat: write: ping 192.168.10.100
└─1814 heartbeat: read: ping 192.168.10.100
juil. 19 10:11:28 lab-web2 heartbeat[1806]: [1806]: ERROR: MSG[2] : [dt=1388]
juil. 19 10:11:28 lab-web2 heartbeat[1806]: [1806]: ERROR: MSG[3] : [protocol=1]
juil. 19 10:11:28 lab-web2 heartbeat[1806]: [1806]: ERROR: MSG[4] : [src=ns1.http.fr]
juil. 19 10:11:28 lab-web2 heartbeat[1806]: [1806]: ERROR: MSG[5] : [(1)srcuuid=0x55e2a1445530(36 27)]
juil. 19 10:11:28 lab-web2 heartbeat[1806]: [1806]: ERROR: MSG[6] : [seq=d0e]
juil. 19 10:11:28 lab-web2 heartbeat[1806]: [1806]: ERROR: MSG[7] : [hg=64b6ebbd]
juil. 19 10:11:28 lab-web2 heartbeat[1806]: [1806]: ERROR: MSG[8] : [ts=64b79ab0]
juil. 19 10:11:28 lab-web2 heartbeat[1806]: [1806]: ERROR: MSG[9] : [ld=0.06 0.16 0.11 2/261 1703]
juil. 19 10:11:28 lab-web2 heartbeat[1806]: [1806]: ERROR: MSG[10] : [ttl=4]
juil. 19 10:11:28 lab-web2 heartbeat[1806]: [1806]: ERROR: MSG[11] : [auth=1 a29d11e0dbf6ca8c4b77b2]
```

This what i've found in the log

```
Jul 19 00:00:00 lab-web1 heartbeat: [554]: ERROR: authtoken does not match, authtoken=84713aff88a7be86584a90e588f01543c>
Jul 19 00:00:00 lab-web1 heartbeat: [554]: ERROR: netstring authentication failed s=###11:(0)t=status,12:(0)st=active,10:(0)dt=1388,13:(0)protocol=1,18:(0)src=ns2.http.fr,27:(1)srcuuid=T�oyWROɮz|[؟��,11:>42:1 84713aff88a7be86584a90e588f01543c693071a,, autotoken=1 84713aff88a7be86584a90e588f01543c693071a, 
Jul 19 00:00:00 lab-web1 heartbeat: [554]: ERROR: MSG: Dumping message with 12 fields 
Jul 19 00:00:00 lab-web1 heartbeat: [554]: ERROR: MSG[0] : [t=status] 
Jul 19 00:00:00 lab-web1 heartbeat: [554]: ERROR: MSG[1] : [st=active]
Jul 19 00:00:00 lab-web1 heartbeat: [554]: ERROR: MSG[2] : [dt=1388] 
Jul 19 00:00:00 lab-web1 heartbeat: [554]: ERROR: MSG[3] : [protocol=1] 
Jul 19 00:00:00 lab-web1 heartbeat: [554]: ERROR: MSG[4] : [src=ns2.http.fr] 
Jul 19 00:00:00 lab-web1 heartbeat: [554]: ERROR: MSG[5][(1)srcuuid=0x55fee60962c0(3627)] 
Jul 19 00:00:00 lab-web1 heartbeat: [554]: ERROR: MSG[6] : [seq=10f3] 
Jul 19 00:00:00 lab-web1 heartbeat: [554]: ERROR: MSG[7] : [hg=64b6f224]
```

I've verified the authkeys file in

```
/etc/heartbeat/auhtkeys
```

and everything is fine.

On both servers in my cluster there is the same error. But everything works fine, thats weird. My collegue is trying to install and make *dnssec* on our cluster of DNS in the same lab, it can be related ? I've tried to reboot servers, to restart the service but nothing else happened.

*Debian 11 x64 & apache2*